# A peculiar quote from Oliver Heaviside

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, mathematical-physics, quote, heaviside

> The best result of mathematics is to be able to do without it.

The above is a quote by Oliver Heaviside, an electrical engineer and mathematician. What does the quote really mean?

Comment: You can get more context for the quotation here (unfortunately I can't copy-paste): https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=--ILBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22The+best+result+of+mathematics+is+to+be+able+to+do+without+it.%22&source=bl&ots=bXrMmiaQZr&sig=0xHcINXdQ65ZaYJeMNNCCgJLav4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7g-zAu-vaAhXEKsAKHfC8AMUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20best%20result%20of%20mathematics%20is%20to%20be%20able%20to%20do%20without%20it.%22&f=false

Comment: Yep,  page 47 of that reference covers it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I have no shame, I screen-shotted the reference that J.G.  found:

[image]
[image]